# How to specify a type in a function call and use that type in another function call, then return object of that type?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a function that could be used to load resources cast as any specified type. Here's what I'm trying to do (which is obviously wrong) but is there a correct way to achieve this, or is it not possible?
[image]

```
public T[] GetResources<T>(string path)
{
   return Resources.LoadAll<T>(path);
}
```

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues OP *did* also post it as text though...

Answer (score 2):

You pretty much got it, `LoadAll` accepts a template where `T` is an `UnityEngine.Object` so you just need to make sure you are also passing in a `UnityEngine.Object`.

```
public static T[] GetResources<T>(string path) where T : UnityEngine.Object
    {
        return Resources.LoadAll<T>(path);
    }
```

Comment: Just leaving this here for OP: The keyword you are looking for is [Type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) ;) in your case `Resources.LoadAll` has a constraint that `T` **has to** be derived from `UnityEngine.Object` => your generic parameter `T` need to comply with that and underly the same constraint: `where T : UnityEngine.Object` as correctly answered here